# tooltip for text cell

Tags: swing, jtable

I have a JTable which contains text cells.
I want to have pretty general feature - if text doesn't fit in cell  I want to display it in tooltip.
Should I use `TableCellRenderer` for that or such simple feature may be done easily (probably just setting some flag?)

also I need to gray-out non-editable cells.

Comment: what do you mean by "disabled"?

Comment: "disabled" means that cell editor can not be opened to edit this cell

Comment: aka: !editable - please get your technical vocabulary right

Comment: fine :-) [some more chars to keep the forum soft happy - how crazy is that ....]

Answer (score 1):

you should use a ToolTip, either a specialized one like Netbeans' (I think that's the origin) Viewtooltips with its dedicated manager (following link contains a reference to the original)

http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/java-concepts/34-core-java/59-tips-and-tricks-for-jtree-jlist-and-jcombobox-part-i.html

or re-use the normal tooltip mechanism, this involves:
- measuring the size-requirement of the cell by configuring its renderer, and comparing the rendering component's pref width with the actual column width, if necessary, set the tooltip accordingly
- some logic in a JTable subclass to detect if that special tooltip is necessary and position at the upper leading corner

Edit (second part of question, config color of not-editable cells)

same way as every configuration of the rendering component: in a custom renderer, basically

```
// we are in getXXRenderingComponent
if (table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
    setForeground(normalColor);  
} else {
    setForeground(notEditableColor);
}
```

Or use SwingX (can't resist, can I :)

```
Highlighter hl = new ColorHighlighter(HighlightPredicate.READ_ONLY, 
     null, notEditableColor);
table.addHighlighter(hl);
```